# Работа с динамической библиотекой d3dx9d_33 в С++

Tags: c++, directx

Не могу понять как правильно работать с библиотекой `d3dx9d_33.dll`. Я не хочу подключать *.lib файлы, а напрямую получать адрес функций и запускать ее, передавая все нужные аргументы. Но в интернете нигде нет примера, где я мог бы понять хотя бы простейшую инициализацию окна. По крайне мере я не смог найти. Во многих больших проектах эти библиотеки находятся в корневой папке игры и их игровые движки прямо их использует. Я бы хотел так же, если вы меня правильно поняли. Желательно, если кто знает, может будет ссылка на книгу, где автор делает акцент на использование DirectX 9 для динамического программирования. Или ссылка на сайт, спасибо за любую помощь!!!

Comment: direct3d это библиотека на C++, не пытайтесь свести ее к вызовам API в стиле C. Не получится.

Comment: *"не хочу подключать *.lib файлы"* - ¿Почему? *"Во многих больших проектах эти библиотеки находятся в корневой папке игры"* - И они при этом подключают .lib файл. *"нигде нет примера, где я мог бы понять хотя бы простейшую инициализацию окна"* - все эти примеры уже есть в составе SDK. А еще последняя актуальная версия была 43, хотя вообще-то весь directX 9 уже давно устарел. Используйте DirectX 11/12.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не хотите полключать lib, то есть вариант динамического связывания.

```
HRESULT InitDx9(HWND wnd)      {
    HRESULT __stdcall (*DirectDrawCreate2) (GUID         *lpGUID, IDX_DirectDraw** , void**) = 0;
    IDX_IDirect3D9 * d3d = 0;
    HRESULT rs= 0;
    IDX_IDirect3D9* __stdcall (*Direct3DCreate9)(UINT SDKVersion) = 0;
    int ver = 32;
    HMODULE d3 = LoadLibrary("D3d9.dll");           
    if (d3!=0) {                    
        *reinterpret_cast<FARPROC*> ( &Direct3DCreate9) =   GetProcAddress(d3,"Direct3DCreate9");           
        d3d = Direct3DCreate9(ver);
       ///....  и так далее
     }
```

LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress. C  GetProcAddress в зависимости от версии с++ приходится повоевать что бы получить адрес именно функции с нужными параметрами. Не помню работает ли такой вариант с VisualStudio, в крайнем случае, хоть это и не красиво - можно преобразовать адрес через union. Получив "интерфейс" дальше уже попроще.

Аналогичным образом можно подключать DirectDraw.
Если проблемы с CLSID то самый простой выход такой:

```
GUID g;     
hr=CLSIDFromString(L"{54ec77fa-1377-44e6-8c32-88fd5f44c84c}",&g);
```

но не запрещено делать и другие более сложные формы записи

Comment: А если к примеру я захочу создать буффер? Как мне его риализацию выгрузить с библиотеки?

Comment: В lib нету реализации, вся реализация в dll. Связывание с dll идет или через lib или через LoadLibrary. Возможно я не понимаю что именно вы хотите, добавьте в вопрос явный пример того что не выходит.